# Asp.Net 4.0 Server Control Client Scripts not defined in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, undefined-reference, requiredfieldvalidator, client-side-validation

In my Asp.Net Web Form Application Client Validation scripts are missing. on my web page i have following field validator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valPrice" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ValidationGroup="valGrpCalculator" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="True" />
```

I have 3 other similar kind of validators for each text field. At the end i have a button which should just postback the page after validation.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitCalculator" aria-controls="mortgage_calculation_results" class="btn_submit" name="btn_send_form" type="submit" ValidationGroup="valGrpCalculator" runat="server" />
```

When i click on this button it throw following two error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: Page_ClientValidate is not defined

Well the problem is only in Chrome browser. In all other browser application is working fine. On another page i have noticed that __dopostback along with following two hidden field missing.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
```

But for this problem i added these two hiddenfield along with needed __dopostback method per javascript on dom.ready and it resolve the problem.

It seems like Asp.Net can not identify the browser and deal it may be as downlevel browser. i tried following solution which does not work for me.

1. `Adding ClientTarget programmatically in Page_PreRender. 
   protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if ((Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("chrome",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0))
           {
               //Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
               Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
           }
       }`

2 add chrome definition file under application App_Browsers folder

Is this something to do with WebResource.axd or Contents Compression?

In web.config i find following telerik handler defined for .axd.

```
<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
```

What is the reason behind this error? Why all other browser can generate need script and hiddenfields but Chrome does not?

Is there any way to fix the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Everyone

Just a status update here. I have resolved the problem which was actually not relating to Asp.Net, Chrome or any JS validation etc. The problem was in one of third party module for mobile detection. 

http://51degrees.codeplex.com/
Since new version of Chrome is there, this module was unable to understand the browser. actually it overwrite the Request.Browser according to its own definition. Yesterday i find the new browser source DB update from 51degree and now every thing is working as it was before.